# Output interator with map

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>    
#include <map>     
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
   typedef std::map<int, int> Key2NodeMap;
   Key2NodeMap first;
   first[1] = 2;
   first[2] = 2;
   first[3] = 3;
   first[4] = 2;

   Key2NodeMap second;
   second[1] = 1;
   second[2] = 2;
   second[3] = 3;
   second[4] = 2;

   Key2NodeMap m;

   ///std::set_difference(first.begin(), first.end(),
   ///                    second.begin(), second.end(), m.begin());

   ///std::set_difference(first.begin(), first.end(),
   ///                    second.begin(), second.end(), std::inserter(m, m.end()));

  return 0;
}
```

map.begin() return iterator is  bidirectional iterator.
"All forward, bidirectional and random-access iterators that are not constant iterators are also valid output iterators." --- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/OutputIterator/

why the first commented line is invalid?

Comment: As far as I can interpret the error message: `note: synthesized method 'std::pair<const int, int>& std::pair<const int, int>::operator=(const std::pair<const int, int>&)' first required here 
      *__result = *__first1;` the problem is that the key-type is `const int`, hence the pair value cannot be assigned to. Hence, you have to adapt using an inserter.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a valid output iterator because you cannot assign to it, i.e. you cannot do:

```
*m.begin() = std::make_pair( 1, 1 );
```

In actual fact the "key" in the iterator (even a regular iterator) is const, so the error is breaking of constness. A `const_iterator` has a const value too.

This is, of course, because if you could just overwrite the key in a map it would break the integrity, i.e. it would no longer be guaranteed to hold a sorted tree with unique keys.

The correct way to attempt an insert into a map is through

```
m.insert( std::make_pair( 1, 1 ) );
```

and `insert` also allows you to provide a "hint" iterator as to where it might insert. (If this hint is the correct place it makes the insertion constant-time rather than `O(log N)` ).

The provided `std::inserter` function creates an `insert_iterator` for your map.. An `insert_iterator` for a `map` is a bit of a hack. It isn't really an iterator at all, and you cannot use it to iterate through your map. It can in fact only be used to insert elements into your map, but has operator overloads like iterators so it can fit into algorithms.

Comment: If use vector instead of the map, that is ok.

Comment: It works with vector only if the iterators into which you are writing already exists, i.e. the vector already has an adequate size (reserve is not enough) in which case those elements are overwritten with the new values. 

iterators in a std::vector are fully mutable, i.e. you can write into them. In a map, a const_iterator has const everything, a non-const iterator has const key and mutable value.

Comment: Thanks for CashCow. I got a explain in SGI-STL doc.

Answer (score -1):

A Pair Associative Container is an Associative Container that associates a key with some other object. The value type of a Pair Associative Container is pair.